# print all previous and next element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to print all previous image id for a check. Because when I am using the following code to add classes to all previous classes, the images are not added to corresponding classes.

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
   var t=$(this);
   t.prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
   t.nextAll().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
```

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxuz6/2/). On click of any image I want to add previous images to different class and next image to different class.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net / post the markup?

Comment: @Reigel i tried making fiddle plz chk ..

Comment: You are missing a `)` http://jsfiddle.net/cxuz6/3/

Comment: besides the `);` missing at the end, everything works like a charm, what's the problem?

Comment: @ Axel Amthor I WANT TO PRINT ALL PREVIOUS ID??? IN CONSOLE OR ALERT

Comment: @undefined HOW TO PRINT ALL PREVIOUS IMAGE ID'S

Comment: Those images don't have ID attributes!

Comment: @simmi: stop shouting; it's both unnecessary and rude. If you want to get the `id`s of the elements, they'll need to have an `id` assigned first.

Comment: @David Thomas did u hear me shouting ???  i am not , instead u check yourself and stop over reacting , i was asking question not shouting

Comment: @simmi: uppercase is perceived as shouting, and is more difficult to read due to the altered word-shapes. I was trying to nudge you towards behaviour more likely to net you a useful response.

Comment: @ David Thomas you had good intention.. but i know they are helping me so m already calm , uppercase was by mistake i replied them too quick and didn't check the caps lock ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you could use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

For example, to get a comma-separated list of checkbox IDs:

```
var numbers = $(':checkbox').map(function() {
      return this.id;
}).get().join();

alert(numbers);
```

The result of this call is the string, "two,four,six,eight".

Answer (score 1):

Those `img` elements do not have `id` attribute, assuming they will have `id` attribute in near future, you can use `map` method:

```
var ids = t.prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1').map(function(){
      return this.id;
}).get().join();

console.log(ids);
```

> the images are not added to corresponding classes.

However, it seems you want to add a class to the clicked element too, if this is the case use `addBack` method:

```
t.nextAll().addBack().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8an7J/